# Google sign in vs Google Play Services Sign-in

Tags: android, google-play, google-signin, android-instant-apps

In order to be eligible for Android instant play program the developers have to implement Google Play Services Sign-in feature, but there is not to much info about it. Is this the same as the regular Sign-in with Google account or this is something completely different ? Thank you

P.S.
link to the [source](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/instant-play-games-checklist)

Comment: Sign-in for **Google Play** ***Game*** **Services** [is different](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin). Note that the [link #6](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/instant-play-games-checklist#requirements) is misleading.